# Android realm can't build javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class

Tags: java, android, realm

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0"
```

then

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

then build

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already
> >     present: javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue

more:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [32.jar:javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class]
    at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
```

**My Gradle**

```
dataBinding.enabled = true

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

implementation "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0-alpha04"
annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0-alpha04'

implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.0-RC2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0-RC1'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'

implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.2'

implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
implementation 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3'
```

**some info:
everything worked like a charm, before I wanted to import the Realm library to my project**

Comment: What else is in your gradle file? It's kinda conflicting with something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same dependency `com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0-alpha04` with both `implementation` and `annotationProcessor` keyword in your build.gradle

With the newer android gradle plugin version you only need to add

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

In your android configuration, without adding any dependency as described [in the official guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#build_environment)

---

try to remove `implementation "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0-alpha04"` and `annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0-alpha04'` and leave `android.dataBinding = true`, then Clean and Rebuild the project.

Comment: I think that is good, because before I added the realm things, all build worked like a charm. So maybe the Realm is the probleme here. Also the "dataBinding.enabled = true" is in my gradle

Comment: @lacas i think you have problems with the annotations provided by the support libraries. I'll update my answer to let you try another thing

Comment: @lacas can you try to remove `implementation "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0-alpha04"` and
`annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0-alpha04'` and leave `android.dataBinding = true`?  then Clean and Rebuild the project. i've copied all your dependencies in a new project, everything starts working fine when i delete the hardcoded dependencies for databinding.

Comment: @lacas Because you used databinding in the wrong way and something in Realm plugin let this problem arise. Sincerely i don't have time to dig more into this, if you want you can perform more researches yourself to have a full understanding. Good Luck :)

Comment: @lacas can you accept the answer if it helped you? it could be indexed and help others

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding following lines of code to your build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2"
}
```

If that still doesn't work, you could also add something like

```
implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
```

Comment: Neither of them? Huh... that's odd. :|